# Buzzing Sound coming from Nissan Altima engine after accelerating

Tags: engine, nissan, noise

I have a really sharp buzzing sound coming from my 2006 Nissan Altima engine.  The sound starts and stays around as soon as press the accelerator.  Doesn't go away until I turn the car off. I know there are similiar issues like this but didn't know if the acceleration part hints at a specific problem.

Comment: Does the problem happen at idle? Does it happen if the vehicle is placed into neutral and gas is applied? How many miles are on the vehicle? Does it consume any oil? Any other symptoms you're feeling?

Comment: After the first acceleration it happens at idle.  The only time after the acceleration, the sound goes away is by turning the car off.   Car has about 80k miles.  No other symptoms I've noticed.

Comment: Have you made sure that it is in fact coming form the engine? Pop the hood next time you get it to happen and see if you can locate _exactly_ where the noise is coming. Front / Rear / Right / Left of engine.

Comment: Coming from passenger side of engine.

Comment: Have you checked the oil level? If you've had to add any then how much?

Comment: My mother is experiencing the same issue from the front passenger side of vehicle. Only when accelerating, not in idle. Still havent found the issue.

Comment: Do you know what brand oil filter is in her car?  I ended up finding out that could be the cause.  After I replaced with a higher end oil filter the noise magically went away.

Comment: @KingKongFrog Maybe you could answer your own question with how you remedied the engine noise with a better oil filter. I know it's in the comments but, I don't always read the comments, especially when they are hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around I read somewhere to try another brand of oil filter.  I was using a cheap  one when I noticed the buzz.  Once I used a higher end filter, the noise magically disappeared. :)